# How do I make the width of content on my web pages 100%?

Tags: html, css, styles, blogger

How can I make all static pages display full width in all static pages? For example, in all my static pages, I have content occupy only half of all static pages.

Pages with the url structure /p/sample.html are the only ones affected. These are the contact us, about, policy etc static kind of pages.

Those with /2017/10/samplepage.html are not affected. These are the regular blog posts.

My website is actually hosted on google.com

What I have tried:

I have tried this:

```
<b:if cond="data:blog.pageType == "static_page"">

.sidebar {display:none;}
#main-content{width: 100%; float: none; margin: 0 auto;}
.main-content .column-center-inner {width: 900px;margin-left: 0px;}
.blog-posts-wrapper {
float: left;
width: 100%;
margin-right: 1.5%;

<b:if cond="data:blog.isMobile == "false"">
.main-content .column-center-inner {width: 100%;}
```

But it didn't work, I have no idea why. Any input from you will help, please.

Comment: What is a "static page" in this case? Your question isn't clear. Please explain exactly which element isn't behaving as expected, and what you want to happen.

Comment: This is the static page https://cutt.ly/pyvds3N

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove `width:300px` from `.post-outer` on pages

Try this

```
<b:if cond='data:view.isPage'>
  <style>
    .post-outer {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 15px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
  </style>
</b:if>
```

Comment: It worked! But I still want the letters in the content to not kiss the border. It's too close to  border, please.

Comment: Ok, See my answer update. If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted to help others with the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
body {
margin:0;
}
```

Add margin or you can actually give the display:block; inside the body